# Define primitive resolve-time values in attribute on constructor parameter in DryIoC

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, attributes, dryioc

In my code there's a dependency (`MyDependency`) that I want to be resolved in a class (`MyClass`). The dependency has a few dependencies itself as well as a primitive constructor parameter (`primValue`), that should be defined by the resolving class. There are other classes besides `MyClass` that also depend on `MyDependency`, but they all use different values for `primValue`.

```
public class MyDependency : ISpecificDependency
{
    public Dependency(IDependencyA depA, IDependencyB depB, int primValue)
    {
        /*...*/

        this.primValue = primValue;
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IDependencyC depC, IDependencyD depD, ISpecificDependency specDep)
    {
        /*...*/

        this.specDep = specDep;
    }
}
```

I know a way to do this would be to change the constructor of `MyClass` as following, but that is pretty ugly because I try to inject the container itself as rarely as possible:

```
public MyClass(IDependencyC depC, IDependencyD depD, IContainer container)
{
    /*...*/

    this.specDep = container.Resolve<ISpecificDependency>(args: new object[] { 123 });
}
```

But **my question is, if something like this could maybe also be achieved by using attributes**. What I'm thinking of would be something similar to this:

```
public MyClass(IDependencyC depC, IDependencyD depD, [DependencyArguments(123)] ISpecificDependency specDep)
{
    /*...*/

    this.specDep = specDep;
}
```

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to provide the primitive value on resolution:

1. Via `Func<MyPrimitiveType, MyService>`: `container.Resolve<Func<int, MyClass>>()(123)`
2. Via global rule `container = container.WithDependencies(Parameters.Of.Type<int>(req => req.Parent.Any(p => p.ImplementationType == typeof(MyClass)) ? 123 : 42))`

There are also a number of [ways to specify the value on registration](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/SpecifyDependencyAndPrimitiveValues.md#injecting-value-of-primitive-type).